# How to set Request.QueryString into variable in select * from variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I set Request.QueryString into variable in a `select * from variable` query?

Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [pm1], [s1], [i1], [j1] FROM ([pk1] = @pk1)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="pk1" QueryStringField="pk1" DbType = "String" Direction = "Input" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near '='.

Comment: Well, SQL definition is wrong: `SELECT fields FROM table` is correct, but not `SELECT fields FROM table = param1`.
Am I missing something?

Comment: i want to use parameter from url as table

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet to get the QueryString value in your query.

```
//get the value from the querystring
string qsValue = Request.QueryString["pk1"];

//create a new SqlDataSource instance
SqlDataSource source = new SqlDataSource();

//add the connectionstring to the source
source.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString();

//create the query with the selectparameter
source.SelectCommand = "SELECT s1, i1, j1 FROM myTable WHERE (pk1 = @pk1)";

//replace the parameter with the value from the querystring
source.SelectParameters.Add("pk1", qsValue);

//bind the gridview
GridView1.DataSource = source;
GridView1.DataBind();
```